# How to remove grey layer on half transparent button when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton

I would like to disable the grey layer that appears when a button is pressed. My button has a special shape and a part of it is transparent.

**Not pressed:**

[image: Not pressed]

**pressed:**

[image: pressed]

My button is inside a UIView. My UIView has a `clearColor()` background. I already tried to set a background image for the button for the state Normal and Highlighted:

`agendaButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forState: .Normal)`
`agendaButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forState: .Highlighted)`

I also tried to set the same image for both states:

`agendaButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "agenda"), forState: .Normal)`
`agendaButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "agenda"), forState: .Highlighted)`

I tried to set the image as a subview of my view and put a transparent button on top:

`agendaView.addSubview(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "agenda")))`

I also tried to set `agendaButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false`
and to set only the image for the `.Normale` state. Or to set the image for both state. I still have the grey layer. I wondered if it was maybe the UIView that becomes grey but apparently not. I set the `UIView` background in red and made the button smaller, and I can see that it is clearly the button that becomes grey and not the UIView.

I tried to do everything programmatically and to set my `UIButton` type as `.Custom` and with `agendaButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false` and `agendaButton.setImage`, then with `agendaButton.setBackgroundImage`, both for `.Normal` and `.Highlighted` state. Same behaviour.

I wonder if there is a way to deactivate this gray layer to come.

The thing is that the white part of the button does not become grey, only the transparent part. I tried multiple solutions I found on SO, but couldn't find any for partially transparent button.

Comment: Try creating the button as custom type (`UIButton(type: .Custom)`)

Comment: @DantePuglisi if I check the type of button in the storyboard it is already of type `Custom`. Should I try to add the button 100% programmatically?

Comment: I'm more of a "100% programmatically" person, although I don't have enough experience with IB so I can't tell which is better

Comment: I also tried to do everything programmatically with `agendaButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false` and `agendaButton.setImage`, then with `agendaButton.setBackgroundImage`, both for `.Normal` and `.Highlighted` state. Same behaviour :(

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the code?

Answer (score 2):

In IB you can uncheck **"highlight adjusts image"**

Programmatically you can use

```
UIButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Similiar options are available for the **"disabled"** state as well.

Comment: Sorry, I also tried that already and it does not work, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I guess all your solution should have helped me.
I didn't saw that at the bottom of by code there was those two lines:
`let color = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 0.3)`        `self.agendaButton.setBackgroundImage(self.generateImageWithColor(color), forState: .Highlighted)`
I feel like I made you lose your time. Thank you a lot for you help.

Comment: That's why you should post your code in the question

Comment: Yes but it thought it would be too long. But I will remember to add way more code next time I ask a question. Thanks!